# Why isnt enum typeclass a subclass of ord typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to know the reasons why enum typeclass does not inherit the ord typeclass. The succ function in enum essentially imposes an order on the values and yet ord is not a required constraint.

Edit:
Also, for other functions in the typeclass, there seems to be an implicit assumption about ord operators being defined for them. As shown here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo

> a possible implementation being enumFromTo n m | n <= m = n : enumFromTo (succ n) m | otherwise = []

Comment: When thinking about why `Enum` does this or that, it's always best to start with the knowledge that it's a fundamentally broken class. Don't try to make sense of it. Use it for convenience and otherwise ignore it.

Comment: @dfeuer Broken because of stuff like `[0, 0.1 .. 0.3]` or broken in more fundamental ways?

Comment: “The `succ` function in enum essentially imposes an order...” — Not really. For example, `succ 2 :: Double` is `3`. Does that mean `2.5` is not greater than `2`?

Comment: @monocell, that's just a broken instance. To see how broken the class is, start by suggesting some useful laws relating multiple methods to each other. See where everything immediately falls apart.

Comment: @dfeuer, I've always though of Enum as things that can straightforwardly be embedded in naturals. Meaning `succ` is `toEnum . (+1) . fromEnum` etc. If i think this way then it is broken in a similar way to `Read`. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @leftaroundabout. I see what you mean but having succ 2:: Double be 3 seems odd to me. Is there some rule (explicit or implicit) on what a succ function can and cannot be?

Comment: @judekanil well that's David's point: _no_, the `Enum` class doesn't really have any proper specification what it can and can't do. It's kind of just, “types where people will get an idea what you mean by a range-list”.

Comment: @monocell For what it's worth, note that `[0.0, 0.1 .. 0.3]` works fairly reliably, since rounding errors are far smaller than what's checked. The list will always be 4 elements long, the last element being 0.3+/- some rounding error. What is really bogus is `[0.0, 0.1 .. 0.25]` which can be of length 3 or 4 depending on the rounding, since `0.25` falls exactly between two elements of the sequence. In retrospect, `Enum Double` should not exist.

Comment: The comments are getting a bit off-topic; the fact that some types with an `Enum` instance aren't *really* enumerable doesn't explain why `Ord` isn't assumed or required.

Answer (score 1):

The `Ord` typeclass is meant to represent *total* orders, which among other things requires transitivity: if `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c`.

A superclass should be necessary for the definition of an instance of a class.

An `Enum`, though it might *impose* an order (though not a necessarily total one) on its elements, doesn't *use* or *require* a total ordering.

As an example, consider everyone's favorite decision-making algorithm:

```
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Enum RPS where
    succ Rock = Paper
    succ Paper = Scissors
    succ Scissors = Rock
```

The `Ord` instance derived from the definition is total, and straightforward: `Rock` is the smallest element, `Scissors` the largest, and `Paper` comes between.

The order implied by this enumeration isn't total. Given `succ`, you might assume that `Rock < Paper` and `Paper < Scissors`, but then `Rock < Scissors` should be true, which is *not* implied by `succ Scissors = Rock`.

The `Ord` instance wouldn't be useful in defining the `Enum` shown above.

---

Unfortunately, a proper instance declaration should use `toEnum` and `fromEnum`, from which all the other methods (including `succ`) can be derived. This makes the definition a little more verbose. Following the model of [`DaysOfWeek`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12/docs/src/Data.Time.Calendar.Week.html#line-38)

```
instance Enum RPS where
    -- *We* know that n `mod` 3 has 3 possible results, but
    -- the exhaustivity checker does not, so use _ in place of 2
    toEnum n = case n `mod` 3 of
                  0 -> Rock
                  1 -> Paper
                  _ -> Scissors

    fromEnum Rock = 0
    fromEnum Paper = 1
    fromEnum Scissors = 2

    -- The generated definitions don't handle wrapping. Without these,
    -- [Paper..Rock] would produce [], not [Paper, Scissors, Rock].
    enumFromTo wd1 wd2
            | wd1 == wd2 = [wd1]
    enumFromTo wd1 wd2 = wd1 : enumFromTo (succ wd1) wd2
    enumFromThenTo wd1 wd2 wd3
            | wd2 == wd3 = [wd1, wd2]
    enumFromThenTo wd1 wd2 wd3 = wd1 : enumFromThenTo wd2 (toEnum $ (2 * fromEnum wd2) - (fromEnum wd1)) wd3
```

Comment: I disagree with this necessity argument. That doesn't mesh with a lot of classes. You don't need `fmap` to define `>>=`, for example.

Comment: Not directly, but `>>=` has to obey the law `fmap f xs === xs >>= return . f`.

Comment: The instance is invalid, as the minimum definition is requiring `toEnum` and `fromEnum`. The `DayOfWeek` in `time` is real life complete example: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.12/docs/src/Data.Time.Calendar.Week.html#line-38

Comment: Thanks, I didn't give that much thought.